# Run a jQuery function when an element is viewed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently i have a load more button running when an element is clicked, as can be seen here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).on('click', '#loadmore', function() {

         etc....
     });
</script>
```

but is there a way to make this run when a div comes into the view of the browser? really turning it into an infinite load?  I've been searching around and cant find any solutions, but it seems like something that is likely possible.

So a user will be browsing down the page, views element `<div id="#loadmore">` and the function runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this plugin [jquery-appear](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/).

Comment: So there is no native built in ability for this, a plugin is necessary?

Comment: @JimmyBanks What do you mean by native built? Yes, jQuey self does not support this.

Comment: But you are normally forced to do it yourself. I just did it some days ago: I will post my code here as well, but I would more rely on a project that is made to be simple to use.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the following method, even though i would recommend using the library version suggested by xdazz

```
//returns the size of the whole html
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}

//returns the size of the browser window
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if ( !( 'innerWidth' in window ) ){
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] }
}

//register a scroll listener, that checks if you are at the end of the page
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop()+viewport()["height"] >= getDocHeight() ){
         //your method here
         loadMore();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.addEventListener)
{
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
          var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
          if(div.offsetTop <= window.innerHeight)
          {
               clearInterval(timer);
               // call your functions here
          });
}
else if(window.attachEvent)
{
     window.attachEvent("onscroll", function() {
          var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
          if(div.offsetTop <= window.innerHeight)
          {
               clearInterval(timer);
               // call your functions here
          })
}
```

Answer (score -2):

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

The jquery visible selector will work

Comment: Just because an element isn't in the viewport doesn't mean it isn't `:visible`.